# Changing boolean value on document click

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, var

sorry for this very basic question but it's makes me crazy, I don't understand what is not working on this very simple Jquery code.
I just want to change my "abc" boolean from false to true when clicking on my document and launch an alert when "abc" is true (just for exemple).

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

  var abc = false;

  $(document).click(function(){
   abc = true;
  });

 if (abc == true){
   alert("ALERT"); 
   //do some other things
 }


});
```

Somebody to help ? Thanks

Comment: You need to place the `if` statement *within* the `click` handler, otherwise it only runs when the page loads. In fact, the entire `abc` boolean flag and `if` condition logic is entirely redundant - just call your `alert()` in the click handler.

Comment: Why you dont put alert in click function

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by JavaScript using an `event model`. This is your piece of code with detailed explanations:

```
var abc = false;

$(document).click(function() {
  // Note that this function is attached to the `click` event
  // It will be triggered only when the `click` event is triggered
  // This means that the code inside it is not executed at the moment
  abc = true;
});

// abc is false at the moment so the if statement won't execute
if (abc == true) { 
  alert("ALERT"); 
  //do some other things
}
```

To fix this, just put the `if` statement inside the click handler and it will work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    

  var abc = false;

  $(document).click(function(){
    abc = true;

    if (abc == true){
      alert("ALERT"); 
      //do some other things
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That’s a bit tautological :)

Comment: `This is caused by JavaScript being asynchronous` No it's not. It's caused by Javascript using an event model.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah sorry for the wrong explaination.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, it works fine.
But with this I can’t do what I want. My goal was to create a variable which is true when I  click on my document and wrong when i don’t click. After that, I want a list of action being triggered only when the var is wrong ==> so I want my actions being triggered all the time except when I click on my document.  I think the method I use is not the good one X)

Answer (score 1):

Your alert won't launch because it is not inside the click handler. It executes only once when document loaded and stays calm. You should move your checking inside click

```
$(document).click(function(){
   abc = true;
  if (abc == true){
   alert("ALERT"); 
   //do some other things
 }
  });
```

moreover, for boolean values you can directly write the varaible name inside if condition as if expect a boolean anyway

```
if (abc == true){
```

can be shorten to

```
if (abc){
```

### So, after putting all your pieces together,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var abc = false;

    $(document).click(function() {

        abc = true;

        if (abc) {
            alert("ALERT");
            //do some other things
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```